# Can't understand the way BasicActivity project shows the layout it auto generated

Tags: android, layout, android-widget

I'm pretty new with Android. I'm trying the understand the look that is shown from the auto-generated xml code when creating *Basic Activity* project.
The files that are auto generated:

1.activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2.content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The way i understand xml, i expected not to see the *FloatingActionButton* widget at all, because when including *content_main* , the root of the *content_main* xml has attributes *android:layout_width="match_parent"* and *android:layout_height="match_parent"*, so this xml should take all the place that is left in the *main_activity* xml (after placing his first child: the Toolbar). Instead according to android designer it seems that the *content_activity* contains the *FloatingActionButton*, how is it possible? isn't it brother of content_activity and son of the root *CoordinatorLayout*?

attached a screen shot to emphasize the situation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read about how 'CoordinatorLayout' View Work and the same concept of it is FrameLayout is support 'z-index' position .

so when the auto generate layout is overload is accept because the reason i mention it .

Try switch between :

```
  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

to be show as :

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

if floationButton not show , that's mean it'w work in z-index .

Comment: i made the change you suggested but the result is still the same. Can you guess what is the problem?

Comment: @Eitanos30 this text from Android Documentation about FloatingActionButton :

Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.

focus in : floating above the UI 

link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: i read the information in the link. **But**, when i'm replacing the *FloatingActionButton* with let's say 'TextView' i'm still getting exactly the same result. Am i doing  something wrong?

Comment: @Eitanos30 that's mean the CoordinatorLayout' is get behavior  of Frame layout and put view in z-index .
try when replace FloatingActionButton with TextView : rearrange between Include and TextView .

Comment: i just checked and it still seems exactly the same. I put the include under the TextView and it's acts exactly the same at it above the TextView

Comment: that's magic i will ask a my mentor may be can have a answer for this thing.

Comment: Thanks. I will also try to deep into it. Unfortunately there aren’t many good Android developer as in other programming language so sometimes it difficult to get a solution for all the issues we encountered